# How to concatenate the output tables of ploop by rows?

Tags: datatable, concatenation, dolphindb

I have a script as follows:

```
def getTable(n){
    t = table(1..2500 as id)
    t["org"] = rand(n,2500)
    t["orgdiv3"] = rand(n\3,2500)
    t["orgdiv6"] = rand(n\6,2500)
    t["orgdiv9"] = rand(n\9,2500)       
    t.rename!(t.colNames()+string(n))
    return t
}

result = ploop(getTable,0+(1..1000)*10 )
finalResult = result[0]
for(i in 1..(size(result)-1)){
    finalResult = finalResult.join(result[i])
}
```

I want to concatenate the output tables of the function `ploop` by rows. I have tried a `for` loop but it takes about 10s. Does anyone have a quicker method? If so, can you share some best practices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the output tables into matrices and then use the `concatMatrix()` function to concatenate them, as shown in the following script:

```
def getTable(n){
    t = table(1..2500 as id)
    t["org"] = rand(n,2500)
    t["orgdiv3"] = rand(n\3,2500)
    t["orgdiv6"] = rand(n\6,2500)
    t["orgdiv9"] = rand(n\9,2500)       
    t.rename!(t.colNames()+string(n))
    matriX = matrix(t)
    colName = t.colNames()
    return matriX,colName
}

timer{
    result = ploop(getTable,0+(1..1000)*10 )
    value,colName = result[,0],(result[,1]).flatten()
    output =concatMatrix(value).rename!(colName)
    tmp = table(output)
}
```

This method takes about 300ms, which is about 30 times faster than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think `union/unionAll` is for "concatenate tables by rows", right?

Please try:

```
result = ploop(getTable,0+(1..1000)*10 )
unionAll(result, false)
```